# Oracle Error when replacing package body

Tags: oracle, database-size, oracle-xe

I get the following error when replacing a package body:

```
Fehlerbericht -
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12953: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 11 GB
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
       (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
       can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

It worked before today, but not anymore. I changed the package body and added a few lines.

After getting the error I shrunk a big table to make room, as I suspected the table was eating into the 11 GB limit, so there should be enough space now.

I also restarted the database host.

What else can I do to improve the situation, or to at least diagnose the issue?

Here is a printout of the table spaces:

```
SYSAUX      795     5       800     1
UNDOTBS1    776     1272    2048    62
USERS       2       98      100     98
TS_DATA     6992    1824    8816    21
SYSTEM      377     1671    2048    82
```

Can I use `ALTER TABLESPACE TS_DATA RESIZE 8G;` to make things work again?
What about `ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\TS_DATA.DBF' RESIZE 8G;`? Which one is correct?

Update: I tried `ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\TS_DATA.DBF' RESIZE 8G;` and it fails because there are used extends at the end of the datafile (ORA-03297).

Comment: Are you running 11g XE?

Comment: yes, the version info says `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`